# Aggregation query making elastic datanode offline due to long GC

Tags: java, elasticsearch, garbage-collection

we are running 5 node cluster version 2.3.5. one as a client node and 4 node configured to work as Data and Master nodes. all nodes has 32GB heap size. below are the JAVA OPTS with which process is configured.

`-Xms32g -Xmx32g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true`

now we are running below search query on index XYZ of 97GB which is making ES nodes to go offline because of long GC run.

`{"from": 0,"size": 0,"query": {"bool": {"must": {"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"id": {"query": "9999","type": "phrase"}}},{"match": {"cltp": {"query": "encounters","type": "phrase"}}}]}}}},"_source": {"includes": ["COUNT"],"excludes": []},"aggregations": {"eid": {"terms": {"field": "eid","size": 200},"aggregations": {"COUNT(DISTINCT eid)": {"cardinality": {"field": "eid","precision_threshold": 40000}}}}}}`

below is the shard distribution of index.
`DN1: Replica 0,2,3
DN2: Primary 0,1,4
DN3: Primary 2,3
DN4:Replica 1,4`

during the query node DN1 and DN4 falling out of cluster due to long GC cycles. below are logs for same.
`DN1:
[2017-11-10 08:27:25,898][INFO ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.134] [gc][old][1076][3] duration [7.4s], collections [1]/[7.4s], total [7.4s]/[16.9s], memory [31.5gb]->[31.8gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [614.5mb]->[865.3mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [0b]->[107.4mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [30.9gb]->[30.9gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:28:17,615][INFO ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.134] [gc][old][1077][18] duration [1.2m], collections [15]/[1.2m], total [1.2m]/[1.5m], memory [31.8gb]->[31.8gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[865.3mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [107.4mb]->[108mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [30.9gb]->[30.9gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:28:49,877][INFO ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.134] [gc][old][1080][26] duration [12.1s], collections [2]/[12.1s], total [12.1s]/[2.1m], memory [31.8gb]->[31.8gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[865.3mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108mb]->[108mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [30.9gb]->[30.9gb]/[30.9gb]}`

`DN4:
[2017-11-10 08:26:36,566][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1074][32] duration [2.3s], collections [1]/[2.4s], total [2.3s]/[11.2s], memory [19.6gb]->[20.4gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [17.5mb]->[8.7mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [19.5gb]->[20.3gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:38,016][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1075][33] duration [1.3s], collections [1]/[1.4s], total [1.3s]/[12.5s], memory [20.4gb]->[21.3gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [8.7mb]->[26mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [20.3gb]->[21.2gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:39,693][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1076][34] duration [1.5s], collections [1]/[1.6s], total [1.5s]/[14.1s], memory [21.3gb]->[22.1gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [26mb]->[28.4mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [21.2gb]->[22gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:41,217][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1077][35] duration [1.4s], collections [1]/[1.5s], total [1.4s]/[15.6s], memory [22.1gb]->[23gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [28.4mb]->[27.4mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [22gb]->[22.8gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:42,990][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1078][36] duration [1.6s], collections [1]/[1.7s], total [1.6s]/[17.2s], memory [23gb]->[23.8gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [27.4mb]->[17.4mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [22.8gb]->[23.7gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:45,167][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1079][37] duration [2s], collections [1]/[2.1s], total [2s]/[19.3s], memory [23.8gb]->[24.7gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [17.4mb]->[34.6mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [23.7gb]->[24.5gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:47,178][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1080][38] duration [1.9s], collections [1]/[2s], total [1.9s]/[21.2s], memory [24.7gb]->[25.5gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [34.6mb]->[35.2mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [24.5gb]->[25.4gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:48,714][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1081][39] duration [1.4s], collections [1]/[1.5s], total [1.4s]/[22.7s], memory [25.5gb]->[26.3gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [35.2mb]->[25.9mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [25.4gb]->[26.2gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:50,547][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1082][40] duration [1.7s], collections [1]/[1.8s], total [1.7s]/[24.4s], memory [26.3gb]->[27.2gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [25.9mb]->[27.5mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [26.2gb]->[27gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:52,066][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1083][41] duration [1.4s], collections [1]/[1.5s], total [1.4s]/[25.9s], memory [27.2gb]->[28gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [27.5mb]->[26.1mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [27gb]->[27.9gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:26:53,067][INFO ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][young][1084][42] duration [879ms], collections [1]/[1s], total [879ms]/[26.7s], memory [28gb]->[29.3gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [26.1mb]->[472.2mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [27.9gb]->[28.7gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:27:04,654][WARN ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][old][1086][2] duration [10.3s], collections [1]/[10.4s], total [10.3s]/[10.4s], memory [30.5gb]->[31.3gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [25.9mb]->[450.2mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[0b]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [30.4gb]->[30.9gb]/[30.9gb]}
[2017-11-10 08:27:12,423][INFO ][monitor.jvm ] [10.0.1.95] [gc][old][1087][3] duration [7.7s], collections [1]/[7.7s], total [7.7s]/[18.1s], memory [31.3gb]->[31.8gb]/[31.8gb], all_pools {[young] [450.2mb]->[865.3mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [0b]->[105.6mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [30.9gb]->[30.9gb]/[30.9gb]}`

curl -XGET "10.0.1.35:9200/_cat/allocation?v"

`shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host       ip         node
   263       61.2gb   259.6gb    232.4gb      492gb           52 10.0.1.95  10.0.1.95  10.0.1.95
   263       75.4gb   308.7gb    183.2gb      492gb           62 10.0.1.134 10.0.1.134 10.0.1.134
   263       78.4gb   346.4gb    145.6gb      492gb           70 10.0.1.89  10.0.1.89  10.0.1.89
   263       81.8gb   274.8gb    217.1gb      492gb           55 10.0.1.85  10.0.1.85  10.0.1.85`

Question: how can we stop or minimise GC "STOP-THE-WORLD" issue?

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your nodes? 64GB? Have you followed the [best practices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html) in heap sizing?

Comment: @Val system ram is 62GB. its an AWS machine. and swappiness is completely disabled. however we found that on 32GB heap JVM UseCompressedOops is getting disabled.

will try to set the cluster heap to 31GB and then again execute the query.

Comment: You need to make sure that when starting you see this in the logs `compressed ordinary object pointers [true]`. It is probably not the ned of the story, but it's a first step.

Comment: @Val decreased the heap to 31gb then restarted the cluster. checked logs for "compressed ordinary object pointers [true]" it is true.
when executed the query still cluster went offline. and on all Data nodes GC kept running continuously how ever we have set the "-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75".

Comment: OK, now... please update your question with the info your get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v` and `curl -XGET localhost:9200/indices?v`

Comment: @Val updated the question.

Comment: what about indices and how many CPUs do you have on each data node (263 shards seems like a lot to handle for a single node)?

Comment: @Val curl -XGET localhost:9200/indices?v it gave error "index_not_found_exception". each node has 16 CPU